# Is there an analogue of the module of differentials for "higher order derivations" in the Hochschild/cyclic senses?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, hochschild-cohomology, derivations, cyclic-homology, kahler-differentials

Note added by YC: the definition below of the cyclic sub-complex is incorrect; and the "higher order derivations" referred to here are traditionally known (since the 1940s) as n-cocycles.

---

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{\mathrm{Ker}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{\mathrm{Der}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$While reading about Hochschild cohomology, I learned that we could define derivations in terms of the Hochschild complex: writing
\begin{align*}
    M &\xrightarrow{d^1} \Hom_{\Mod_R}(S,M)\\
      &\xrightarrow{d^2} \Hom_{\Mod_R}(S\otimes_RS,M)\\
      &\xrightarrow{d^3}\Hom_{\Mod_R}(S\otimes_RS\otimes_RS,M)\\
      &\xrightarrow{d^4}\cdots.
\end{align*}
for the Hochschild cochain complex of an $R$-algebra $S$ with coefficients in an $S$-bimodule $M$, we have
$$\Der_R(S,M)\cong\Ker(d^2).$$
Now, derivations play an important role in deformation theory, and we can build an  universal object corepresenting them, the **module of differentials** $\Omega_{S/R}$ of $S$ over $R$, defined by
$$\Hom_S(\Omega_{S/R},M)\cong\Der_R(S,M).$$
Naturally, this leads one to wonder about whether we have a similar universal object for the module
$$\Der^{n}_R(S,M)\cong\Ker(d^{n+1})$$
of "$n$-order Hochschild derivations of $S$ into $M$". For example, here's what such a higher derivation looks like for $n=2$ and $n=3$ (where below we identify a map $D\colon S^{\otimes_R n}\to M$ with the unique $n$-multilinear map $D\colon S^{\times n}\to M$ it represents):

- A **second order Hochschild derivation** is a map $D\colon S\otimes_R S\to M$ satisfying the equation
  $$D(ab,c)-D(a,bc)=aD(b,c)-D(a,b)c$$
  for each $a,b,c\in S$.
- A **third order Hochschild derivation** is a map $D\colon S\otimes_RS\otimes_RS\to M$ satisfying the equation
  $$D(ab,c,d)-D(a,bc,d)+D(a,b,cd)=aD(b,c,d)+D(a,b,c)d.$$
  for each $a,b,c,d\in S$.

Lastly, we could also work with the cyclic complex of $S$ with coefficients with $R$, defining "higher cyclic derivations" in a similar manner. These satisfy one extra equation:
$$D(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(-1)^{n-1}D(a_n,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}).$$
So again, in the low degree cases, we have $D(a,b)=-D(b,a)$ and $D(a,b,c)=D(c,a,b)=D(b,c,a)$.

Now, write $\Der^{\mathrm{cycl},n}_R(S,M)$ for the set of "$n$-order cyclic derivations", and note that given an $S$-module morphism $f\colon M\to N$ and an $n$-order (cyclic) derivation $D$, the composition $f\circ D$ is still an $n$-order (cyclic) derivation. This gives us functors $\Der^{n}_R(S,-)$ and $\Der^{\mathrm{cycl},n}_R(S,-)$.

> **Question.** The above two functors are corepresentable by $\Omega_{S/R}$ when $n=1$. Are they also corepresentable for $n\geq2$ (in the commutative case)?

Comment: (Also, if yes; how are these related to the usual "universal objects" found in deformation theory, like the de Rham complex or the cotangent complex?)

Comment: I think people usually consider rather higher derivations or Hasse-Schmidt derivations, and for these there is a module of differentials. Googling should turn up both old papers of Nakai and such people, on one hand, and much more recent developments  ("Hasse-Schmidt algebra" is a good keyword to find these)

Comment: What is your definition of a derivation with values in a module? All definitions known to me require the target to be a bimodule.

Comment: In general there's a thing called (Connes-)Tsygan calculus, which is a most reasonable known generalisation of interplay between de Rham complex and polyvector fields on a smooth/algebraic manifold to an arbitrary ring. If you want higher derivations for some other reason, probably it's better to formulate that reason first, at least vaguely.

Comment: What are $D^n$, $D^k$ in your first notion? Do you, perhaps, actually want to start with a sequence of linear maps $D^0,\dotsc,D^n$?

Comment: As @MartinBrandenburg points out, your $D^n$ does not make sense. The usual definition is inductive. An $R$-linear map $D: S\to M$ is an $n^{th}$ order derivation, if $[D,s]$, the Lie bracket is a derivation of order $n-1$ for all $s\in S$. The universal object is got as usual by taking the sequence. $0\to I\to S\otimes_R S\to S\to 0$ and consider $S\otimes_R S/ I^{n+1}$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This sounds really cool; I didn't know Hasse–Schmidt derivations had a notion of module of differentials too! Thank you for the pointers =)

Comment: @DenisT I meant $\phi\colon R\to S$ to be a morphism of commutative rings, so that we can speak of modules without specifying whether they are left, right, or bi. In general these definitions will all require $M$ to be a bimodule indeed. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @DenisT I don't really have a motivation for higher derivations yet (except that perhaps "order two derivations" in the Hochschild sense are related to algebraic deformation theory); my idea was to first see if these notions admit an analogue of the "module of differentials", and then study those objects to see what (if anything) they have to say about deformation theory.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry for the confusion! $D^n$ here means $D$ composed with itself $n$ times. (While I don't really expect this to be of much interest, it still seems like a mildly interesting question, since $d^n$ with $d$ a derivation becomes an "$n$-order derivation" in this sense and since maybe one might join the set of those for all $n$ to get a graded ring.)

Comment: @Mohan Hi Mohan! As I explained in a comment above, I meant $D^n$ to be the composition of $D$ with itself $n$ times. I'm not really too keen on it being an interesting notion, but I wonder if it might still be of some use, since a(n ordinary) derivation composed with itself $n$ times is an example of this notion, and thus maybe we could join the sets of these things into a graded ring with composition as the operation.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh and by the way, the notion you mention with a sequence of linear maps $D^0$, $\ldots$, $D^n$ is an interesting one: it's developed on e.g. [Section 1 here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14171) (the only difference being we don't include the binomial coefficients in the above "higher Leibniz rule")

Comment: The composition makes sense only for endomorphisms, not a map $ D:S\to M$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mohan Oh you're right of course, these only make sense when $M=S$! I've removed them from the question, thanks!

Comment: I am rusty on the relevant algebra, but what you call "order n derivations" look to me like n-cocycles in the Hochschild chain complex, and using this terminology might help you to find further references. (For the basic general definitions concerning Hochschild cohomology, Weibel's book has a useful chapter, although it does rely on earlier chapters for explanations and proofs)

Comment: Also, the notation in your formulas indicates that M is being considered as an S-bimodule, but if you want to extend the formalism of Kahler differentials then presumably you want S to be commutative and M to be a **symmetric** S-bimodule i.e. $s\cdot m =m\cdot s$. In general, Hochschild cohomology makes sense for noncommutative algebras and general bimodules, and you should specify which setting you're in if you are looking for (co-)representable functors - this already makes a difference in the n=1 case

Comment: @YemonChoi Since this is a commutative algebra question, modules are understood to be symmetric in this context.

Comment: @Emily The notation is still not quite right. You want to write $D(a \otimes b)$ when you define $D$ on $S \otimes S$.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks! I meant these "order n derivations" to be defined precisely as Hochschild $n$-cocycles; I've rewritten the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was identifying $D$ with the unique $R$-bilinear map $D\colon S\times S\to M$ associted to it (I've edited the question to clarify this)

Comment: Your edited version of the question still uses the terminology "order n derivations" for something which already has accepted standard terminology, namely "Hochschilfd n-cocycle". I don't really understand why you are inventing non-standard terminology instead of using standard terminology. Worse still, the term higher-order derivation is already used for something different.

Comment: @YemonChoi It's to motivate the question, as they look like a natural analogue of derivations but in higher degrees. (In any case I can't change the terminology/notation above anymore (apart from adding the qualifier "Hochschild" to disambiguate with the usual ones), as Martin's answer refers to it)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, you have defined cyclic cocycles incorrectly: they are (special kinds of) n-cocycles which take values in Hom_R(S,R), and not in a general coefficient module M as you claim. So a cyclic derivation can be viewed as a function $S \times S \to R$, a cyclic 2-cocycle as a function $S\times S\times S \to R$, and so on. With the definition you have tried to make above, I don't think you get a subcomplex - the cyclic symmetry has to involve the coefficient module if you look at the original definition of Connes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *yes* and it is very simple. It helps to understand the case $n=1$ first in the way I explained in my [thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716) in Prop. 4.5.3. Namely, $\Omega^1_{S/R}$ can be constructed as the quotient of the right $S$-module $S \otimes_R S$ by the $S$-submodule generated by those $ab \otimes 1 - b \otimes a - a \otimes b$ with $a,b \in S$.

Similarly, a representing object of $\mathrm{Der}^2_R(S,-)$ can be constructed as the quotient of the right $S$-module $(S \otimes_R S) \otimes_R S$ modulo elements of the form
$$(ab \otimes c) \otimes 1 - (a \otimes bc) \otimes 1 - (b \otimes c) \otimes a + (a \otimes b) \otimes c$$
with $a,b,c \in S$. So every time you use the $S$-module structure on $M$ in the definition of the derivation, you just put the scalar into the last tensor factor. This works by the very construction of the adjunction between scalar extension and scalar restriction.

The general definition is similar. For the cyclic variant you have to quotient out another relation.

Comment: Since the OP has chosen not to update the terminology: the traditional notation in Hochschild cohomology for ${\rm Der}^n_R(S, -)$ is $Z^n_R(S,-)$, and elements of this space have been known for 80 years as cocycles not "higher derivations"