# Has anyone attempted to generalize the notion of a higher differential of $ A $ and the sheaf of differentials $ \Omega_{A/k} $?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Over a field $ k $ of characteristic zero, actions of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on a variety $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ are obtained from $ A $-derivations $ \delta $ of $ A $ over $ k $ via the co-action below:
\begin{equation*}
a \mapsto \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\delta^{j}(a)t^{j}}{j!}.
\end{equation*}
The sheaf $ \Omega_{A/k} $ parameterizes $ A $-derivations of $ A $ over $ k $.

If $ k $ is a field of positive characteristic then actions of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ are parameterized by iterative, higher derivations.  A collection of $ k $-homomorphisms $ \phi_{i}: A \to A $ is a higher derivation if $ \phi_{0} = \operatorname{id}_{A} $ and $ \phi_{n}(a_{1}a_{2}) = \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{2}} \phi_{i}(a_{1}) \phi_{j}(a_{2}) $.  A higher derivation is called iterative if $ \phi_{i} \circ \phi_{j} = \binom{i+j}{i} \phi_{i+j} $.  One obtains an action of $ \widehat{\mathbb{G}_{a}} $ on $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ from an iterative, higher derivation $ \{\phi_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $ via the co-action below:
\begin{equation*}
a \mapsto \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \phi_{j}(a)t^{j}.
\end{equation*}

One could generalize the notion of a $ B $-derivation of $ M $ over $ A $ as follows.  Let $ J_{B/A} $ be the kernel of the ring homomorphism $ B \otimes_{A} B \to B $ which sends $ b_{1} \otimes b_{2} $ to $ b_{1}b_{2} $.  Define $ \delta_{i}(b) $ to be the image of $ b \otimes_{A} 1 $ in $ J_{B/A}^{i}/J_{B/A}^{i+1} $ so that the image of $ b $ in $ \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} J_{B/A}^{i}/J_{B/A}^{i+1} $ is $ \{\delta_{i}(b)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $.  A higher $ B $-derivation of $ M $ over $ A $ is a homomorphism $ \phi: B \to \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} J_{B/A}^{i}(B \otimes_{A} M)/J_{B/A}^{i+1}(B \otimes_{A} M) $ such that if $ \phi_{i}(b) \in J_{B/A}^{i}(B \otimes_{A} M)/J_{B/A}^{i+1} $ and $ \phi(b) = \{\phi_{i}(b)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} $, then $ \phi_{n}(b_{1}b_{2}) = \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{2}, i+j=n} \delta_{i}(b_{1})\phi_{j}(b_{2}) $.  However, there might be a more optimal way to generalize the notion of a $ B $-derivation of $ M $ over $ k $ to higher derivations so that one could define a sheaf $ \Xi_{A/k} $ with a similar universal property to $ \Omega_{A/k} $.

Has anyone tried to generalize the notion of higher differentials so that one could create a sheaf $ \Xi_{A/k} $ with a similar universal property to that of $ \Omega_{A/k} $ for derivations?  Specifically are there any references in the literature of such a generalization and sheaf $ \Xi_{A/k} $?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434693

Comment: I am not sure if the question is well-defined. For the definition of $\Omega^1_{A/k}$ we need the notion of a derivation $A \to M$ where $M$ is any $A$-module. In the description using $\mathbb{G}_a$-actions only derivations $A \to A$ appear. In your proposed definition of $\Xi_{A/k}$ we also only talk about maps $A \to A$ and even *compose* them. How are we supposed to generalize this to maps $A \to M$?

Comment: We would need to generalize the notion of a higher differential to define higher derivations of $ A$ into $M $ over $ k $.  That is meant to be included in the question.

Comment: I believe there is a way to make such a generalization, and I want to know if it is already in the literature.

Comment: I see. Then it would be very helpful if you add this generalization to the post. Also, when you are just looking for literature, the tag "reference request" is useful.

Comment: In your edit, $\mathrm{gr}_I(M) = \bigoplus_n I^n M / I^{n+1} M$ needs to be replaced by $\prod_n I^n M / I^{n+1} M$, for otherwise we have some extra condition that locally all derivations eventually vanish.

Comment: Thank you @MartinBrandenburg!  I have made the appropriate edits.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't think the question you link to is related, because of the reasons I have mentioned over at that question (and this is why I wish people would call Hochschild cocycles "cocycles" rather than inventing their own terminology).

Comment: You are right. -

Comment: @Schemer1 I'm not much familiar with these, but I think maybe Hasse–Schmidt derivations might be what you're looking for. In particular, I think [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14171) defines higher derivations in Section 2 in a similar way as you did above and constructs an analogue $\mathbb{HS}_{A/k}$ of the module $\Omega_{A/k}$ for these. Section 4 seems to globalise a similar object to $\mathbb{HS}_{A/k}$ to the setting of schemes and then relate it to jet spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Emily.  This does seem to be what I was looking for.

Comment: @Schemer1 It's my pleasure! I'm happy you found these pointers helpful =)

Answer (score 2):

I have this strange feeling I have commented on this or an identical question recently, but can't place it.

Here is one solution which may not be what you are looking for and you have mentioned it in your question.

Let $A$ be a $B$- algebra (all commutative) and let $M$ be an $A$-module. A $B$- module homomorphism $D:A\to M$ is a differential operator of order $\leq n$, if $[D,a]$, the Lie bracket, is a differential operator of order $\leq n-1$ for all  $a\in A$. Of course differential operator of order zero is just an $A$-module homomorphism.

Then the universal object is got as follows. Let $J$ (as in question) be the kernel of the multiplication map $A\otimes_B A\to A$. For any $n$, one has the $A$- module $D_n=A\otimes_B A/J^{n+1}$  where the module structure is from the left factor, say. Then one has a $B$-module map $d:A\to D_n$ given by $d(a)=1\otimes a$ and one can check that this is a differential operator of order $n$ and has the required universal property.

Comment: Maybe it was https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434693.